# Defining a relationship between a schema and a render function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

`render` is a function that renders JSX components, based on a given schema.

The `render` function receives two arguments:

1. `schema` object.
2. `components` record.

### The `schema` param

The schema type can represented as (Example):

```
type Schema<S> = {
  order: (keyof S)[];
  sections: S;
};
```

A schema example would be:

```
const schema = {
  order: ["key1", "key2"],
  sections: {
    key1: {
      type: "componentA",
      settings: {
        someSetting: "Hello, world!",
      },
    },
    key2: {
      type: "componentB",
      settings: {
        title: "Title",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

1. The schema `order` is list of random string keys to render.
2. The schema `sections` is a object/record.
3. Here we can notice that ever the `order` is an array based on the `section` keys. Or vise-versa.

### The `components` param

1. The `components` its a record where every key may be either a `string` or the schema sections `type`(maybe just `string` to simplify?)
2. The value is a function that receives a random string the `settings` for that corresponding component in order to render a JSX component.

### Implementation

Implementation:

```
export const render = (schema, components) => {
  return schema.order.map((key, index) => {
    const section = schema.sections[key];
    if (!section) {
      return null;
    }

    const componentFunc = components[section.type];
    if (!componentFunc) {
      return null;
    }

    return componentFunc(`${String(key)}-${index}`, section.settings);
  });
};
```

Use case:

```
render(schema, {
  componentA: (key, settings) => {
    return <p key={key}>{settings.}</p>;
  },
  componentB: (key, settings) => {
    return <p key={key}>{settings.title}</p>;
  },
})
```

### Question

How to properly type this implementation? Particularly, how to express that `componentA: (key, settings)` receives `settings` of that particular component type?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3o5jm) what you're looking for?  (I hope we can focus on the call side and not worry about the implementation of `render` much.) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?